# How i can use gdb to check who accesses the memory of an Eigen matrix?

Tags: memory, gdb, eigen

suppose my class has a member Eigen::Matrix  alpha;
How I can check from gdb whihc function write in its space. 
From Eigen i can get its address using alpha.data and it should be stored in 100 size_of(double) bytes after this address.

Answer (score 1):

[Watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)

If the array containing your data is static, GDB should be able to find out the size of the array, so `watch alpha.data` should tell you whenever any value in the array changes. However, if data is a pointer, `watch alpha.data` will tell you when the pointer changes, and not when the data in your array changes, which is not very useful. You will then need to manually tell GDB to watch the region occupied by your array: `watch (double[100]) *alpha.data`.